# Filter a list of case class objects based on a list of strings

Tags: string, list, filter, scala-collections

I have a case class as this User(id:String, name: String, address: String, password: String) and another case class as Account(userId: String, accountId: String, roles: Set[String]). I need to filter a list of Account objects ( List[Account]) based on a list of userIds which I have as a List[String] in Scala. I have been struggling with this and tried doing this but couldn't. Any pointers on how should I do this would be really helpful.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you're only trying to keep only `Account`s for which the `userId` is part of separate collection that you have, you can do it like this:

```
val accounts: List[Account] = ???
val idsToKeep: Set[String] = ???
accounts.filter(a => idsToKeep.contains(a.userId))
```

For the record, if you use the `contains` method a lot, you are better off using a `Set[String]` than a `List[String]` to store the ids to keep.